# Can downgrading OS make Xperia Neo V, boot after a boot loop

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, boot, boot-loop

My *Neo V MT11i* was upgraded to ICS a few days ago. Today when I turned on bluetooth, it started to reboot repeatedly.

I tried to hard reset using sets of button as posted in some blogs but still I can't access it.

Is there any solution? Does downgrading to Gingerbread solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a forum post, the OP has a similar problem to the one you have:

- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2151177

He said that he just flashed his device with the stock firmware and it fixed the problem, so it's worth a try.

---

Here is the flash tool:

- http://androxyde.github.com

4.1.B.0.587 Firmware ftf file:

- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=33295129

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Sony's own Update Service](http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/tools/update-service/). It's very easy to use, and you can chose the Android version you wish to install if I'm remembering it right.